# Hyundai Sonata 2012 Car starting problems

Tags: starting, hyundai, intermittent-problems, sonata

I am residing in UAE and it hot summer season here( 45 degree +). I have Hyundai Sonata 2012 model car. I am using this car for last 7 months. It was running fine till this summer. I am noticing starting problems often. I usually drives in high traffic road for 1 hour daily. I drove 25 kms and stopped at a parking lot & turned off engine today. Then i decided to change the parking lot and tried to start the car. Its not starting(Engine cranks, then stops. seems weak battery, but battery indicator shows green and healthy). This happened last week as well. But when i started it after 8 hrs, it worked.Please suggest what might be the actual problem.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: When you say the "engine cranks", what do you mean? Can you hear the cylinders firing, or do you just hear the sound of starter motor running? If only the starter motor is running, it should make a "whirring" noise. In theory, it is easier for the battery to start a hot engine than a cold engine. Determining if the battery is bad is easy; an auto mechanic or shop that sells batteries can test the battery for very cheap/free.

Answer (score 0):

I'll bet it's Crankshaft Position Sensor. It's a one bolt sensor beside the timing belt. All you have to do, go buy a used part for fraction of the cost. You will get an engine check after this and it will say "crankshaft position sensor" but you can clear it when car is turned off.

Crankshaft position sensor cuts fuel by sending wrong info to ECU. Disclaimer: I'm not a mechanic but these are things I learned on my own.